# If you know the windows administrator password is there any way to get past UAC programmatically?

Tags: security, winapi, uac

Just wondering.... I know that the Win32 API has functions to impersonate a user , but I read that in Windows 7 and Vista that these only work when ran as admin which defeats the purpose.

Comment: You read wrong. UAC does not restrict the ability to impersonate users.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the only way to bypass UAC is to create a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). This will not ask for credentials when elevating to administrative priveleges.

Comment: I think, although I'm not certain, that you can do it with a scheduled task, as well.

Comment: You can, if you don't want to distribute the program it's [very easy to get around UAC for a specific program](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/135472-faq-what-is-the-uac-part2/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't bypass UAC, you use it.  Separate your admin tasks into a separate process, then log into the user account using LogonUser() and launch that process in an elevated state using CreateProcessAsUser().